# Join elements of a nested list based on condition

Tags: python, arrays

I have a nested array called `element_text` in the form of for example:

```py
[[1, 'the'], [1, 'quick brown'], [2, 'fox jumped'], [2, 'over'], [2, 'the'], [3, 'lazy goat']]
```

And would like to concatenate the elements in the array and return a new array called `page_text` as so:

```py
[[1, 'the quick brown'], [2, 'fox jumped over the'], [3, 'lazy goat']]
```

So, if the first number is the same, join the second text strings together with a space in between.

I've tried:

```py
page_text = []

for i in element_text:
    #join the list of strings together if the page number is the same
    if i[0] == i[0]:
        text = " ".join(i[1])
        page_text.append([i[0], text])
```

But this just returns the same array as what was there in the first place.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,

Carolina

Comment: `if i[0] == i[0]` How would this ever not be true?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**:

You can use pandas by grouping the records by your number and joining all the strings together into a new column.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 'the'], [1, 'quick brown'], [2, 'fox jumped'], [2, 'over'], [2, 'the'], [3, 'lazy goat']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['num','text'])

df['full_text'] = df.groupby(['num'])['text'].transform(lambda x : ' '.join(x))
df = df[['num','full_text']].drop_duplicates(subset='num')

df.head()

#   num full_text
#0  1   the quick brown
#2  2   fox jumped over the
#5  3   lazy goat
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is easier to manipulate later on!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

By using `itertools`, a native python library, you could construct the list of lists in an one-liner.

```
from itertools import groupby

inp = [[1, 'the'], [1, 'quick brown'], [2, 'fox jumped'], [2, 'over'], [2, 'the'], [3, 'lazy goat']]
out = [[key, ' '.join([text for _, text in group])] for key, group in groupby(inp, key = lambda x:x[0])]

print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 'the quick brown'], [2, 'fox jumped over the'], [3, 'lazy goat']]
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that was possible. Very ice.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you build a list of the text pieces in a dictionary based on a key of the "id" using `setdefault()`. Once that dictionary was assembled I would then reshape it into the list you seek.

```py
data_in = [[1, 'the'], [1, 'quick brown'], [2, 'fox jumped'], [2, 'over'], [2, 'the'], [3, 'lazy goat']]

data_out = {}
for key, value in data_in:
    data_out.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
data_out = [[key, " ".join(value)] for key, value in data_out.items()]

print(data_out)
```

That should give you:

```
[[1, 'the quick brown'], [2, 'fox jumped over the'], [3, 'lazy goat']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the sorted list to a dictionary and concatenate the strings for each key

```
def convert_and_concatenate(lst):
    lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])
    dictionary = {}
    for item in lst:
        key = item[0]
        value = item[1]
        if key in dictionary:
            dictionary[key] += " " + value
        else:
            dictionary[key] = value
    return dictionary

lst = [[1, 'the'], [1, 'quick brown'], [2, 'fox jumped'], [2, 'over'], [2, 'the'], [3, 'lazy goat']]
result = convert_and_concatenate(lst)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought of a dictionary.

```py
x = [[1, 'the'], [1, 'quick brown'], [2, 'fox jumped'], [2, 'over'], [2, 'the'], [3, 'lazy goat']] 

y = {}
for k, v in x:
    y[k] = (y.get(k, '') + f' {v}').strip()
y = [[k, v] for k, v in y.items()]
print(y)
```

output:

```
[[1, 'the quick brown'], [2, 'fox jumped over the'], [3, 'lazy goat']]
```